# How do i make div content downloadable to txt file?

Tags: php, html, security

My website generates a unique key(password) for each account to login. It is important, confidential, and unrecoverable. So how do I make it downloadable as txt for everyone.

This the code:

```
echo '<h2>';
print "Welcome  $username  to your dashboard<br>";

}
echo "</h2>";
echo "<p>";

$sec_value = 'usqi3289';
$rdecrypted_text = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_DES, $sec_value, $userkey, MCRYPT_DECRYPT); 

echo "<div class='button special'>Your Userkey: <font color='black'>$rdecrypted_text</font></div>";
?>
 <br><p align="center">Please save your Userkey first,This is confidential and unrecoverable, because we don't hold any passwords. </p>
```

Mainly this one:

```
"<div class='button special'>Your Userkey: <font color='black'>$rdecrypted_text</font></div>"; ?>
```

I want a button below that so people click on it and it downloads a txt file containing this `userkey`.

Comment: Can you create button using HTML and bind event click on it using javascrit/jQuery for example?

Comment: I am not too sure about this one,But i can add a button below that, but it should be connected with $rdecrypted_text

Comment: That is fine. And then in click event you can make ajax request to your server and fetch txt file?

Answer (score 1):

You can put this code in a `PHP file`, e.g. `userkeydl.php`:

```
<?php

    header("Content-type: text/plain");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = userkey.txt");

    print "Your Userkey is: \n";
    print $rdecrypted_text;
    print "\nPlease note that this is confidential and unrecoverable.";

?>
```

Comment: We cal also look for alternatives, like something that download the div contents into txt file

Comment: @user3265050 You can print the `div` contents in your `txt` file